# Flights from London to the US?

Tags: usa, uk, london, lhr

I need them to be on May 23, early morning, preferably even before 10 A.M.

Can anyone help me find some? I'm looking all over the web, but I can't find any. I need flights that are confirmedly happening, like the Air France one from Paris to NYC 3 days a week that you can book from Air France's website.

Comment: Note that the usual pattern for transatlantic flights is that they depart Europe in the afternoon, arriving in North America early evening; in the other direction they depart North America late evening and arrive in Europe in the morning.  Flights departing Europe in the early morning are rare under normal circumstances and with reduced schedules due to COVID they may be completely gone.  If you have to be in the US earlier on the 23rd then you may have to depart the previous day.

Comment: [We are not Travel Agents™](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1445/105640)

Comment: @NateEldredge that possibly depends where you’re going. I’ve got many flights from Heathrow and Gatwick to the eastern US which have left London early to mid morning. It can be very useful to get to the US just after lunch.

Comment: @rhialto Found a flight with British Airways, so I guess I'm set for now.

Answer (score 3):

The *United 15* flight is still operating with *Austrian Airlines* and *Lufhtansa* as a code share, are still operating direct flights from London Heathrow (LHR) to New York Newark (EWR).

Sample flights found using *Skyscanner* below:

[image]

Comment: I was about to answer something similar by looking at the heathrow departure schedule https://www.heathrow.com/departures

Comment: @NateEldredge good point, edited post